# Ctable forces new page after section title

Tags: tables, ctable

I have multiple `ctable` which are filling about a page each. One of them is smaller and therefore used as the first one so that a section title can be printed on the top of the page.

Now `ctable` makes automatically a new page, leaving the section title on a blank page and starting the table one page after. If I put the same code into a `tabular` environment everything works like a charme.

Here is the page head when using a `ctable` (noting the space above the table):
[image: page with ctable]

Her is the page head when using a `tabular` (section title appears):
[image: page with tabular]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section with ctable}

\ctable[notespar,caption={Caption},botcap]{cc}
{}{
\toprule
TEST & TEXT\\
\midrule
test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\
\bottomrule
}

\newpage
\section*{Section with tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
TEST & TEXT\\
\midrule
test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\test& text \\
\bottomrule
\caption{Caption}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding  the specifier `pos=hb` helps and places the `ctable` directly under the section title.

Comment: Doesn't work here; better use `pos=!h`.  Also better use `\FL` for `\toprule`, `\ML` for `\\\midrule`, `\LL` for `\\\bottomrule`, `\NN` for ` \\ `, And: `\caption` inside a tabular environment generates an error...